# Is there a way for laravel execute seeder for the first time launch on Docker?

Tags: php, laravel, docker-compose

I'm using Laravel with Docker. The first time I run docker-compose build and docker-compose up seems like it's doing well. But when I stop docker and start again (or up and down again) then come the error duplicate entry because the seeder had run again.

This is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM php:7.4-fpm-alpine

RUN sed -i 's/https/http/' /etc/apk/repositories

RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql sockets
RUN apk add libzip-dev && docker-php-ext-install zip

RUN apk --no-cache add pcre-dev ${PHPIZE_DEPS} \
  && pecl install xdebug-2.9.2 \
  && docker-php-ext-enable xdebug \
  && apk del pcre-dev ${PHPIZE_DEPS}

CMD php artisan migrate --seed && php artisan serve --host=0.0.0.0 --port=80
```

This is my error messages:

```
    Seeding: Database\Seeders\UsersTableSeeder

   Illuminate\Database\QueryException 

  SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry
```

I have tried using the environment variable but it's not working for me.

This is how I'm using env

```
   if (!env('SEEDER_HAS_RUN')) {
        // Seeder runs here
        // ...
        putenv('SEEDER_HAS_RUN=true');
```

Please give me a hint :(

Comment: You environment variable is the right idea. I would ace your logic in an `entrypoint.sh` file which does that running. Maybe let PHP figure it out instead of bash. The "it's not working for me" is more interesting. You have your Laravel. You have your ... let's say 'install' command. If "seeder_has_run" === true, then do nothing, otherwise call "artisan command run seeder"

Comment: @UnderDog I think in my case, the problem is the env('SEED_HAS_RUN') always FALSE whenever I try docker stop and start again. So it's always run seeder one more time which cause above error

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow (SO) @KhoaAnhTran! Your docker-compose file is missing from the question, edit the question and add it. Same for the error you describe, show the command, and then the output with the error message. Do not use screenshots. If you have any questions, please ask.

Comment: Is `users` table supposed to be empty before seeding (by chance)?

Comment: @Tpojka At the first time running, yes. But when I launched and stop docker then start again, the seeder run again cause error

Comment: It is good practice to set as first line of `UsersTableSeeder::run` method something like `if (0 < User::count()) {return;}` so you prevent seeding in case something is already in table. I use this concept of checking often.